# Find:File in Perl - Search through symlink directory

Tags: perl, file-find

Does anyone know how to make File:Find can search through symlink directory?

I have a real directory at

```
/home/alex/mydir1
```

and a symlink directory inside

```
/home/alex/mydir1/test -> ../mydir2
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/depot/perl-5.8.3/bin/perl
use strict;
use File::Find qw(find);

my $path = "/home/alex/mydir1";

find(\&Search,follow => 1, $path);

sub Search{
    my $path = $File::Find::name;
    print $path."\n";
}
```

And the result is:

```
/home/alex/mydir1
/home/alex/mydir1/test
```

Why it's not search through /home/alex/mydir2 and print out every files inside ? Can anyone show me how to do that ?

Thank you and best regards.

Alex

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html
$File::Find::fullname

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A close look at the documentation for [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.24.0/ext/File-Find/lib/File/Find.pm) reveals the error:
You have passed a *key-value list* of parameters instead of a *reference to a hash* of parameters.

```
# Incorrect: looks like find(@params)
# asks find to search the list of paths:
#    ( 'follow', 1, $path )
find(\&Search,follow => 1, $path);

# Correct: looks like find(\%params)
find({ wanted => \&process, follow => 1 }, $path);
```